# Can't find the static resources with thymeleaf library in spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to have a quick test of how to use Thymeleaf and please see my two screenshots:

[image]

The home.html is under my templates/ directory, and it can be displayed correctly when I visit http://localhost:8090/. However, it failed to link to the two static files in the bottom of the home.html file:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="js/home.js"></script>
<link href="css/home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Please see the error message:
[image]

I don't have specific thymeleaf configurations except the spring configurations:

```
## web
server.port=8090

## velocity
spring.velocity.allowRequestOverride=false
spring.velocity.allowSessionOverride=false
spring.velocity.cache=false
spring.velocity.checkTemplateLocation=true
spring.velocity.contentType=text/html
spring.velocity.toolbox-config-location=/WEB-INF/toolbox.xml
spring.velocity.exposeRequestAttributes=false
spring.velocity.exposeSessionAttributes=false
spring.velocity.exposeSpringMacroHelpers=false
spring.velocity.resourceLoaderPath=/WEB-INF/templates/
spring.velocity.suffix=.vm
spring.velocity.templateEncoding=UTF-8
spring.velocity.charset=UTF-8
spring.velocity.properties.input.encoding=UTF-8
spring.velocity.properties.output.encoding=UTF-8
spring.velocity.requestContextAttribute=rc

spring.mvc.favicon.enabled = false

logging.config=classpath:log4j2.xml
```

And my controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome(Model model) {
        LOGGER.info("Run Successfully");
        return "home";
    }
```

My main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({WebConfigurer.class})
@ComponentScan("com.jdd.jnlu.qe")
@PropertySource({"classpath:boot.properties", "classpath:important.properties", "classpath:jss.properties",
        "classpath:system.properties", "classpath:ump.properties"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class JnluQEWebStart extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(JnluQEWebStart.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Thymeleaf, try this:

```
<script th:src="@{/js/home.js}"></script>
<link th:href="@{/css/home.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Don't forget to register Thymeleaf in your page:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```